# Trying to filter by an intermediate table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do this query

```
subsidiaries = self.con.query(Subsidiary)\
                    .options(joinedload(Subsidiary.commerce)\
                             .joinedload(Commerce.commerce_tags))\
                    .filter(CommerceTag.tag_id == id)
```

But it doesn't work, so to explain:

The relationship between tables are:

[image: Relationship]

I just want to obtain all the subsidiaries of all the commerces that has an specific tag, i want to do it with Subsidiary has the base class (i know that if i use Commerce it will be more easier), the reason is 'cause i convert it to a json value with the next format:

```
"subsidiaries": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "some_name",
        "commerce": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Commerce Name"
        }
    }
]
```

Well, i can do the query with Commerce has base class, but i think that maybe iterating the commerces to obtain the subsidiaries is more expensive that doing it in the query.

I don't want to load CommerceTag but i had it in joinedload 'cause it doesn't work with Join method.

I need some help to do this :(

Comment: Could you describe how it didn't work? Also since you want it in JSON format, you might able able to use [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) for faster results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
subsidiaries = session.query(Subsidiary)\
                .join(Subsidiary.commerce)\
                .join(Commerce.commerce_tags)\
                .filter(CommerceTag.id == id)
```

Your statement generates the query like this:

```sql
SELECT subsidiary.id AS subsidiary_id, subsidiary....
FROM tag, subsidiary
LEFT OUTER JOIN commerce AS commerce_1 
    ON subsidiary.id = commerce_1.subsidiary_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    tags_by_commerce AS tags_by_commerce_1
    JOIN tag AS tag_1 ON tag_1.id = tags_by_commerce_1.id_tag
) ON commerce_1.id = tags_by_commerce_1.id_commerce
WHERE tag.id = :id_1
```

So tags filtering doesn't have an effect.

And the statement I propose generates this:

```sql
SELECT subsidiary.id AS subsidiary_id, subsidiary.name AS subsidiary_name
FROM subsidiary 
JOIN commerce ON subsidiary.id = commerce.subsidiary_id
JOIN tags_by_commerce AS tags_by_commerce_1 ON commerce.id = tags_by_commerce_1.id_commerce
JOIN tag ON tag.id = tags_by_commerce_1.id_tag
WHERE tag.id = :id_1
```